Link device's gyroscopic orientation with that of 3d model on web
I am trying to build a model rocket that uses an old phone for reading gyroscopic data using a webapp (Flask and flask-socketIO). the "rocket phone" goes to /rocket and sends gyroscope data back to the server using socket io. the server sends this data to clients at /render. the render page uses ThreeJs to render a gltf file with alpha, beta and gamma by changing rotation of x, y and z.
This only works when the phone is placed flat onto a surface (Back of the phone facing down) but when the phone is placed upright (As it is supposed to be in my rocket) it acts weirdly (random snaps and changes).
app.py
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/rocket')
def rocket():
    return render_template('rocket.html')

@socketio.on('send_data')
def handle_send_data(json):
    print(f"Received data: {json}")
    emit('update', json, broadcast=True) 

@app.route('/render')
def gltf_view():
    return render_template('render.html')

rocket.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Gyroscopic Data and G-Forces</title>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='rocket.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Gyroscopic Data and G-Forces</h1>
<div>
    <h2>Gyroscope</h2>
    <p>Alpha (Rotation around Z-axis): <span id="alpha">0</span></p>
    <p>Beta (Rotation around X-axis): <span id="beta">0</span></p>
    <p>Gamma (Rotation around Y-axis): <span id="gamma">0</span></p>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>G-Forces</h2>
    <p>G-Forces: <span id="gforces">0</span> G</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}


rocket.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const socket = io();
    let previousGForce = 1

    if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
        window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handleOrientation);
    }

    if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
        window.addEventListener('devicemotion', handleMotion);
    }

    function handleOrientation(event) {
        const alpha = event.alpha.toFixed(2);
        const beta = event.beta.toFixed(2);
        const gamma = event.gamma.toFixed(2);

        document.getElementById('alpha').textContent = alpha;
        document.getElementById('beta').textContent = beta;
        document.getElementById('gamma').textContent = gamma;

        socket.emit('send_data', { type: 'orientation', alpha, beta, gamma });
    }

    function handleMotion(event) {
        const acceleration = event.accelerationIncludingGravity;
        const gForce = (Math.sqrt(acceleration.x ** 2 + acceleration.y ** 2 + acceleration.z ** 2) / 9.8).toFixed(2);

        if (Math.abs(gForce - previousGForce).toFixed(2) > 0.01) {
            document.getElementById('gforces').textContent = gForce;
            socket.emit('send_data', { type: 'motion', gForce });

            previousGForce = gForce
        }
    }
});

render.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>GLTF Viewer</title>

<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.166.1/build/three.module.js",
            "three/addons": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.166.1/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='render.js') }}" type="module"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1>GLTF Model Viewer</h1>
<div id="container"></div>
{% endblock %}

render.js
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons';

const socket = io();
let scene, camera, renderer, model;

function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    const loader = new GLTFLoader();

    loader.load("/static/rocket.gltf", function (gltf) {
        model = gltf.scene;
        model.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        model.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        scene.add(model);
    }, undefined, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });

    camera.position.z = 5;
    animate();
}


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

socket.on('update', function (data) {
    if (model && data.type === "orientation") {
        console.log(data)
        model.rotation.x = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(data.gamma); // Yaw (turning)
        model.rotation.y = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(data.alpha); // Roll (tilting sideways)
        model.rotation.z = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(data.beta - 90); // Pit
    }
});

init();


I like the ambition of your project. It's a cool idea to map the rocket's movement. Is it really necessary to use a smartphone though? Seems like (in addition to only fitting upright) it would add substantial weight to your rocket. Have you considered instead buying a separate gyroscopic accelerometer part and wiring something lightweight together? Also, does the project require that data be sent in realtime, or is it acceptable to retrieve after the rocket's descent?

...and if you do need realtime data, a smartwatch might be better suited than a smartphone.

Thats the problem. I dont have access to a smart watch with the said capabilities.
